# SQL Lookup function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table that has employee info and another that has Manager assignments.
The manager info table references employee table by employee id in addition to managers.
I have been able to left join the table but I want to display the name rather than just employee ID.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',[FirstName],[LastName]) AS FullName,
   [EmployeeID]
  ,[Status]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[ManagersTbl].[ManagerIDf]
FROM [EmployeesTbl]
LEFT JOIN [ManagersTbl] on [EmployeesTbl].[EmployeeID] = [ManagersTbl].[EmployeeIDf]
WHERE Status = 'A'

Manager Table
_____________
| EmployeeIDf | ManagerIDf |
-----------------------------
001T          |      005C
002J          |      005C
_______________________________________________
Employee Table
______________
| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Status |
-----------------------------------------------
001T          |  Tom      |  Spanks  | A
002J          |  John     |  Doe     | A
005C          |  Cruisin  |  Bruisin | A
_______________________________________________
End Result needed
_________________
|EmployeeID | StaffName | ManagerName |
------------------------------------------
001T         | Tom Spanks | Crusin Bruisin
002J         | John Doe   | Crusin Bruisin
```

Comment: Just use the same concatenation you use instead of the ID. You may need to qualify your fields with the table name as the query is now using 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
SELECT 
EmployeeID
, CONCAT_WS(' ',A.[FirstName],A.[LastName]) AS StaffName
,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.[FirstName],B.[LastName]) AS ManagerName

FROM [EmployeesTbl] A
LEFT JOIN [ManagersTbl] M on A.[EmployeeID] = M.[EmployeeIDf]
LEFT JOIN  [EmployeesTbl] B
ON M.[Manageridf]
=B.[EmployeeID]
WHERE Status = 'A'
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Something so simple as adding an additional left join. Thank you! @Abishek

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous routes you can take, one possible solution is to join between your two tables to get your `StaffName` and then use an inline correlated subquery to get the `ManagerName`

```
select EmployeeId, 
    concat_ws(' ',FirstName,LastName) StaffName,
    (select concat_ws(' ',FirstName,LastName) from EmployeeTable em where em.EmployeeID=m.ManagerIDf) ManagerName
from ManagerTable m join EmployeeTable e on e.EmployeeID=m.EmployeeIDf
where e.status='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use concatenation and join with two table by primary key employeeid.

concatenation function or + sign to concat in sql .